# Remove @google from top bar in firefox

Tags: firefox, search

I'm using duckduckgo as my only search provider and in the latest firefox (75?) its top bar added "Search with google". I have checked about:config and I have not found any way to remove it.

Anyone knows how to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer and it is to unpin/remove google from the most vist pages since the top bar shares its links with a New tab

Answer (score 1):

#### Does anyone knows how to remove "Search with google"?

Go to `about:preferences#search` and set the default search engine to DuckDuckGo:

> [image]

The search bar will change to reflect the new default search engine:

> [image]